# Apply retention label to folder in SharePoint Online

Tags: sharepoint-online, retention

I have a SharePoint Online site with different document libraries.  Then I've created different retention labels.
Each document library should have only 1 label applicable to that library.  The user need to apply the label manually, and when the user want to apply it, only the applicable label should appear in the dropdown list.

For example I have retention labels A2, A5, D10, D15.
Library AB, should only have label D15 available to apply manually to the files
Library CD, should only have label A2 available to apply manually to the files

Is this possible and if so, how can I make only the applicable label available in the dropdown when applying a label?